# Validate jsonschema date format

Tags: python, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate the date property of a json object in python.

```
# Define JSON object
json_object = {
    "date": "21ducn23-dsfsd-ds",
    "age": 30
}

# Define JSON schema with date format
json_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "date": {"type": "string", "format": "date"},
        "age": {"type": "integer"},
    },
    "required": ["date", "age"],
    }
} 

# Validate JSON object against schema
jsonschema.validate(instance=json_object, schema=json_schema)
```

But as long as the date field is a string the validation comes through successfully.

I have read several answers to similar questions suggesting that format is annotation only.
It seems that the [documentation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string#built-in-formats) suggests otherwise but I may be missing something.

What can I do to get this to work without defining a regex expression for the date property?

I'm using `jsonschema==4.21.1` and `jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you linked:

> By default, format is just an annotation and does not effect validation. Optionally, validator implementations can provide a configuration option to enable format to function as an assertion rather than just an annotation.

To do that in Python using `jsonschema`, [you need to hook a `format-checking object` into the `Validator`](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validate/#validating-formats).

So just add `format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker()` to your `validate` call:

```py
from jsonschema import FormatChecker

jsonschema.validate(
    instance=json_object, schema=json_schema, format_checker=FormatChecker()
)
```

It will then raise an error:

```
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: '21ducn23-dsfsd-ds' is not a 'date'

Failed validating 'format' in schema['properties']['date']:
    {'format': 'date', 'type': 'string'}

On instance['date']:
    '21ducn23-dsfsd-ds'
```